# REST API Design - Collections as arrays with ETag

Tags: rest

Take the following URL template:

```
~/pupil/{id}/subjects
```

If the subjects are a collection represented in the traditional way, as if each item stands alone like the pupil items, then is this the correct way to expose them?

It begins to feel wrong when you consider updating the collection in terms of the pupil and concurrently with another API caller.

Suddenly, you cannot synchronize access since there's no ETag to cover the set and you'll end up interleaving the changes and getting in a tangle.

A different design could see the subjects incorporated as a sub array in the entity of the pupil and the `/subjects` URL is just for read access.

Perhaps the subjects should be returned as a single array set entity with a discreet ETag and that POSTing individual subjects should be disabled and updates made via a POST/PUT of the whole set, but what if the list is very long? Needs paging?

Maybe the design decision is case-by-case, not a sweeping guideline. Not sure.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to treat "subjects" as a single resource or not.

If, as you say, consumers of your API and going to want to add, remove or modify individual subjects then, yes the traditional way of representing them would be correct with regard to REST patterns:

```
~/pupil/{id}/subjects
```

would return a list of resources at

```
~/pupil/{id}/subjects/{subjectId}
```

Unless there's a strong reason to optimize bulk operations or caching, this is the most RESTful and straightforward implementation.